# Se tiver esse caractere, descarte a captura

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

Como faço para a expressão regular não capturar o que tiver `\}` no texto? Eu quero que obtenha todos os `}`, mas quero que se estiver escapado com o caractere \ seja descartado, não ignorado.

Estou tentando essa expressão: `[^\\]}` mas ela retorna um caractere antes do `}`...

**Resumo:** Se tiver o caractere **\** antes do **}**, **descarte** a captura.

Comment: Não sei em .Net, mas em Pcre, isto funciona: `{(.*[^\\])}`

Comment: Nessa ai ta capturando o campo **{...}** inteiro... só quero que capture os **}** que não seja **\}**...

Comment: Entendi errado. Esta expressão funciona em Pcre (se eu tiver entendido corretamente dessa vez...): `(?<!\\)(})`

Comment: Obrigado @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira, funcionou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No comentário do @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira foi utilizada uma [*negative lookbehind assertion*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) `(?<! subexpression)` para verificar o caractere anterior. A sintaxe em PCRE e .NET é a mesma.

```
(?<!\\)(\})
```

Significa: capture um colchete somente se não houver uma barra invertida antes.

Importante, o grupos começados com `(?` não são contados, então a o grupo `(\})` terá índice 1.

Comment: Sim, eu não queria que os **}** fossem capturados também, mas ai eu coloquei o *not capturing group*, no modo `(?<!\\)(?:\})` e funcionou, após isso o **}** não apareceu nas listas de matches, e pude fazer o `Regex.Split()` normalmente.